# Implementing static functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, oop, inheritance, static

This may sound stupid to all,but I am facing this issue with the static functions in PHP. Still new to OO programming in PHP so need some help.

I have a DB class which handles all the functions for connection and crud operations in my application.I have another class which extends the DB class and uses the methods in it.

```
     class Database(){

          function db_connect(){
                //body
            }
      }

    /*****The inheritor class*****/  
    class Inheritor extends Database{
         function abcd(){
                  $this->db_connect();         //This works good
          }

     }
```

But now I have to use the `function abcd(){}` in a other class as it carries out the same task.The new class is this for example which also extends the database class:

```
     class newClass extends Database{

           function otherTask(){
               //Here I need to call the function abcd();
            }
     }
```

I tried making the `function abcd()` static but then I cannot use the `this` in the function definition in class Inheritor. I also tried creating the object of database class and but that's not permissible I believe as it gave error.

Can someone suggest me the right way to achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: Your `newClass` needs to extend `Inheritor` not `Database`

Comment: Will that also allow me to get access to the `Database` methods?? @ChristopherMorrissey

Comment: Sounds to me like `newClass` should `extend Inheritor`, or that `function abcd` should be a member of `Database`. This is about logically grouping your code and class hierarchy, which is hard to give any advice on without knowing the real purpose of each class.

Comment: if newClass needs access to methods in Inheritor, why wouldn't newClass extend Inheritor? Or you could move shared functions into Database so both child classes have access to them.

Comment: @ChrisRasco `abcd()` internally calls a insert method of `Database`,now I want to use the same function to carry out the operation but in a different class.I cannot move the functions as they are already being used elsewhere in the application in the current form.

Comment: @coderunner that is correct

Comment: Static functions are not attached to any instance, thus you cannot use `$this`. Why do you think you need to have *both* things at the same time?

Comment: @coderunner "I cannot do something because I've already painted myself into a corner" is a bad reason not to do something. You obviously need to *redesign* your class inheritance model, since it obviously doesn't work for you.

Comment: @deceze Yes sir I will definitely work on it,so that I don't have such issues later! But I believe the solution suggested would work good instead of tweaking the model for a single implementation.But I have made a note of it for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply extend the `Inheritor` class. This will give you access to both `Database` and `Inheritor` methods.

```
class NewClass extends Inheritor {
   function otherTask() {
       //...
       $this->abcd();
       //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you extends a  class the new class inherit the previous  methods.
Example:

```
Class database{
Method a(){}
Method b(){}
Method c(){}
}
Class inheritor extends database{
//this class inherit the previous methods
    Method d(){}
}
Class newCalss extends inheritor{
    //this class will inherit all previous methods
    //if this class you extends the database class you will not have 
    //the methods d() 

}
```